# Saving Contenteditable with Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, contenteditable

I want to be able to add a contenteditable area for a client to update text. 
Anyone know the best way to save the changed content to sql db with Coldfusion ?

Comment: What do you have now to which you want to add this feature?

Comment: Nothing yet. But I want to add a simple <div id="thiscontent" contenteditable="true"> This will be the content</div> And then if they are logged in as admin a button is going to display that says 'Save'.

Comment: Are you familiar with html forms?

Comment: Yes. I am a mid-level programmer and I have just got into HTML5/CSS3 responsive designing. I know I can do a simple html form, but I was hoping to learn how to use the HTML5 style contenteditable. Like demonstrated here. http://html5doctor.com/the-contenteditable-attribute/

Comment: It pretty much tells you how to do it in the article you just linked to, you either use a button, or you use javascript to wait for a keypress and fire off an ajax request to your `CFML` that will save it to the DB.